# meteor event to get this.userId just after creating a new user

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteorite, meteor-accounts, meteor-helper

I want to map the id of a user to a name.

Eg: `{A: eSQyPRis4QQfQ5vQT, B: 84m9PFZZj79G9uH8M}`.

So when creating a new user, I want to map his id to a variable. I imagine the code might be like,

```
Accounts.justAfterCreatedAUser({
    values['A'] = this.userId;
})
```

But I couldn't find anything similar.
 How can I achieve this?

Comment: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser

Comment: the 'user' object in onCreateUser had the _id which I want. Thanks!